# align two divs in the middle of the screen with an image inside them

Tags: html, css

I have the following html (minimal) template:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top"><img src="img/hyphen_top.png" width="177" height="150"/></div>
        <div class="bottom"><img src="img/hyphen_bottom.png" width="117" height="6"/></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Using only css, I want to align "top" div in the middle of the page/scree and "bottom" div under the "top" div with a margin top 100px. I can`t center top/bottom and also the images in the main container("container").

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.container {
    text-align:center;
}
.bottom {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5xTLh/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Y8CcW/)

```
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.top {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.bottom {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The image inside "top" container it not seems to be centered in the middle of the screen :(

Comment: It's centered, look at the fiddle.